# Sort By Negative Value in Ubuntu

Tags: unix, sorting, negative-number

I have a problem: I want to sort a file like this from big to little values

```
de la (-0.190192990384141) 
de l (-0.158296326178354) 
la commission (0.041432182043560) 
c est (0.107475708632644) 
à la (-0.112009236677336) 
le président (0.051962088225587) 
à l (-0.095689228439195) 
monsieur le (0.041436304077711)
```

I try with this command

`sort -t "(" -ngk2r file1 > file2`

but I get this

```
de la (-0.190192990384141) 
de l (-0.158296326178354) 
à la (-0.112009236677336) 
c est (0.107475708632644) 
à l (-0.095689228439195) 
le président (0.051962088225587) 
monsieur le (0.041436304077711) 
la commission (0.041432182043560)
```

As you see the file is not sorted.
It seems like a mysterious problem.

Any ideas please?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

i found the solution for this problem

```
env LC_ALL=C sort -t "(" -ngk2r result2.txt >result2tri
```

Thanks